# Bit swapping O(logN)?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, bit

I've been told that reversing bits of an integer in a divide-and-conquer fashion (i.e. by first swapping every two consecutive bits, then swapping 2-bit pairs, and so on until I get the result) is O(logN), but I fail to see how this is O(logN)..

Consider the case when swapping a byte (8 bit): we first swap every two bits together and perform 4 swaps, then we swap 2-bit pairs so we have 2 swaps and then we join everything together in the last swap. Total: 7 swaps, log(N) would have been 3.

Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: O(log n) does not mean that you have to perform log n swaps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just counting something else. If you add up all the "individual swaps", that's a lot of swaps. But the whole point of the technique (and many similar techniques) is that for "phase", all the swaps in that phase happen in a constant number of steps. For example the step "swap adjacent bits":

```
x = ((x & 0x55) << 1) | ((x & 0xAA) >> 1);
```

.. or its equivalent delta-swap formulation, looks like that no matter how many swaps it's doing (the constants change of course). So, that's a constant number of steps right there. (cue complaining about operations on N-bit integers not being single steps, *here they are*, it's just a different way of counting)

It takes 3 delta-swaps (or simple swaps like above) to reverse a byte.

Answer (score 6):

The key observation is that some swaps can be done in parallel. To quote your post:

- *we first swap every two bits together and perform 4 swaps,*
- *then we swap 2-bit pairs so we have 2 swaps*
- *and then we join everything together in the last swap.*

*Total: 7 swaps, log(N) would have been 3.*

Right, it's 7 swaps, but in 3 steps outlined above.

For example, swapping 4 pairs is like `x = ((x & 01010101b) << 1) | ((x >> 1) & 01010101b)`. This way, we take bits 0, 2, 4 and 6 and promote them to positions 1, 3, 5 and 7 (the left half), and simultaneously take bits 1, 3, 5 and 7 and demote them to positions 0, 2, 4 and 6 respectively (the right half).